# Dinamically loading images with require in React has different behaviors

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a scenario in which I want to dynamically tell a child component which image to show, based on an required image passed down by the parent, as such:

**Parent:**

```
function Social() {
    return (
        <SocialBar>
            {
                SocialMedias.map((media) =>{
                    return <SocialApp 
                        key={uuidv4()}
                        link={media.link}
                        social={require(media.icon)}
                    />
                })
            }
        </SocialBar>
    );
}
```

**Child**

```
function SocialApp(props) {
    return (
        <Social href={props.link} target="_blank">
            <CustomSizedImage src={props.social.default} />
        </Social>
    );
}
```

Which seems pretty straight forward, right? However, this causes the error below:
[image]

I've seen some posts say that this is caused because the path is not absolute. However, I tested with absolute paths and it still doesn't work. The funny thing is, when I changed the parent code to the below for testing, it worked.

**New parent code:**

```
function Social() {
    const img = require("../assets/icons/social-media/instagram.svg");
    return (
        <SocialBar>
            {
                SocialMedias.map((media) =>{
                    return <SocialApp 
                        key={uuidv4()}
                        link={media.link}
                        social={img}
                    />
                })
            }
        </SocialBar>
    );
}

export default Social;
```

The result:

[image]

**OBS: I tested with EVERY image that this code will possibly load. Is not an image/image path related issue.**

What is expected of all this is to dynamically load icons for social media with the correct URLs, etc. What I do not understand is: **why does it work when I require the image outside the return?**. I know I could make this work by iterating `media` object outside of return and use the resulting array with the map index, but that doesn't seem clean. Why does it have this behavior? Is there a way to make it work inside the map?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your last code snippet works because the path is known at compile time.

I assume you use a bundler like Webpack or similar. When they compile your project, they check all imports `(including require calls)`, use that to calculate the dependency tree, and finally bundle all required files together. For images, that includes "compiling it into a module" which just returns the path to the image.

Usually that also involves replacing paths with module identifiers. E.g. if you ever looked at the built Webpack code, you'll notice that it doesn't use e.g. `require('./module')` but `__webpack_require.c(5)` or something similar. It gave the module `'./module'` the unique ID `5` in the bundled code.

With your earlier code snippets, when using a dynamic require with a non-constant string, Webpack just doesn't know that you'll request that image. Nor would it know the new unique ID to use for that.

The easiest solution is to import your images somewhere and use those references dynamically:

```js
// images.ts
export IconA from './media/icon-a.svg';
export IconB from './media/icon-b.svg';

// somewhere else
import { IconA, IconB } from './images';
const iconPath = someCondition ? IconA : IconB;
```

---

Of course, you don't have to use the import/require mechanic. You can simply have your icon path be an actual path, relative to your `public/` folder.

Comment: Thank you. This is the first time I actually understand why It doesn't work. I see your point with the imports and the public folder options. From a "clean project" perspective, would you say that having social media icons inside the public folder is better than the require approach?

Comment: Putting things on public seems to be a little against the usual folder structure which is to have an assets folder inside src.

Comment: @William With the require approach, you enjoy the benefit of the path being validated, instead of having to assume it's somewhere in your public folder under the right name. I forgot how exactly it bundles images, but you might also get the benefit of it not including not-used images, if that matters. And with the require approach, perhaps you can use different loaders to e.g. compress the images. Personally I prefer the require approach, even though I only care about the path validation, but the public folder approach is still a valid technique.

Comment: For one thing it really matters is something like Font Awesome icons. You have a module with thousands of icons, often with several versions of the same icon. Outlined, non-outlined, filled in, etc. In that case, benefiting from Webpack only bundling the used icons (most likely using tree shaking) is a big boon.